# How to Assign the Output of comm Command To Variable

Tags: bash, shell, echo, comm

I need assign the Output of **comm** Command to variable. I use comm to campare two list of values.

These two lists are defined as:

```
DATA_REF_DATA_OPIT_SIP='PCSCF4A
PCSCF4B
PCSCF5A
PCSCF5B'
DataExist='PCSCF4B
PCSCF5A
PCSCF5B'
```

**And when i do**

```
comm -23 <(sort <<<"$DATA_REF_DATA_OPIT_SIP") <(sort <<<"$DataExist")
```

**Output :**

```
PCSCF4A
```

I want to assign the output of comm to a Variable. So i did :

```
res=$(comm -23 <(sort <<<"$DATA_REF_DATA_OPIT_SIP") <(sort <<<"$DataExist"));
echo $res
```

I get empty output.

**instead of :**

```
echo $res
PCSCF4A
```

Please Help. Thanks you.

Comment: Yeah it's DataExist and not DataH323.but the output still null

Comment: Provide something I can copy-and-paste to get that null output -- when I run the code at https://ideone.com/A9vlJx, I get the desired output (and so does ideone's online shell, now that it actually ran).

Comment: I think, it's problem of version that i have it

Comment: I doubt very much that this is version-specific. If you're using the same shell for both the line that works and the line that doesn't, then it's already known to support all the necessary syntax.

Comment: Anyhow, can you reproduce the problem when you copy-and-paste the code from my ideone link above (and thus are using that link's variable definitions, exact and unmodified)?

Comment: i get like this output PCSCF4A
PCSCF4B
PCSCF5A
PCSCF5B
PCSCF4B
PCSCF5A
PCSCF5B
when i test the same example what you put in https://ideone.com/A9vlJx

Comment: Are you sure you copied-and-pasted *exactly* from the webpage, without retyping anything? Note that ideone has its own bash interpreter, and it shows the output as `PCSCF4A` from when it ran the code itself.